# Gulp clean css creates duplicate style.min.css files

Tags: css, sass, gulp

When I run gulp default task, gulp clean css creates first style.min.css. When I end this task and start again it creates styles.min.min.css and it happend continuously with adding .min every time so it create multiple style files. Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
    gulp.task('sass', function () {

                // Global Theme CSS Compilation

          gulp.src('./sass/global/**/*.scss')
           .pipe(sass()).pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));        
          gulp.src('./sass/themes/construction/*.scss')
           .pipe(sass()).pipe(gulp.dest('./themes/construction/css'));
       });
   gulp.task('minify', function () {            
                // CSS Minify          
     gulp.src(['./css/*.css','!.css/*.min.css'])
     .pipe(minifyCss()).pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'})).pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
    gulp.src(['./themes/construction/css/*.css',
      '!./themes/construction/css/*.min.css'])
       .pipe(minifyCss()).pipe(rename({suffix: 
       '.min'})).pipe(gulp.dest('./themes/construction/css/'));
   });

        gulp.task('watch',['sass'], function(){
            gulp.watch(['./sass/global/**/*.scss', './sass/themes/construction/*.scss', './sass/themes/corporate/*.scss']);
        });
```

What I need to do to prevent gulp create multiple files but just one and just update it?

Answer (score 3):

You simply forgot a back slash in this line:

```
gulp.src(['./css/*.css',  '!./css/*.min.css'])
```

in the negation part of the glob.